# Exclude one column from group by in a join

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have an aggregated query:

```
SELECT SERIAL, pos_id, MIN(fecha)
FROM pvs 
WHERE pos_id = 50
GROUP BY SERIAL, pos_id
ORDER BY MIN(fecha) DESC;
```

[image: First query]

and it works quite well to get the information I need, except one piece of data which is the id of that serial number in another table. This happens when I make a join.

```
SELECT d.id, p.SERIAL, p.pos_id, MIN(fecha)
FROM pvs p
JOIN devices d
ON d.SERIAL=p.SERIAL
WHERE p.pos_id = 50
GROUP BY p.SERIAL, p.pos_id, d.id
ORDER BY MIN(fecha) DESC;
```

[image: Second query, lots of duplicates]

I wanna show the id of every row in the other table but I can't exclude the Id from the group by (I just need the first date and only the first appearance of that serial number). I.e. i want the first query but adding the id from the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the subquery

```
select  d.id, t.SERIAL, t.pos_id, t.min_fecha
from  devices d 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT SERIAL, pos_id, MIN(fecha) min_fecha
    FROM pvs 
    WHERE pos_id = 50
    GROUP BY SERIAL, pos_id
    ORDER BY MIN(fecha) DESC;

    ) t on t.SERIAL = d.SERIAL
ORDER BY min_fecha DESC
```

or if you need  just one id apply an aggreation funtion

```
SELECT min(d.id), p.SERIAL, p.pos_id, MIN(fecha)
FROM pvs p
JOIN devices d
ON d.SERIAL=p.SERIAL
WHERE p.pos_id = 50
GROUP BY p.SERIAL, p.pos_id
ORDER BY MIN(fecha) DESC;
```

Comment: I get the same result from the second query.

Comment: Do you need to add `AND d.fecha = t.min_fecha` to the join conditions?